# Leaflet map sources

Tags: leaflet, openstreetmap, angular-leaflet-directive

Is there a list for all potential map sources out there? On the sample page one can browse through four types of maps. What else is out there?
http://tombatossals.github.io/angular-leaflet-directive/#!/

Comment: by map source, do you mean basemap tile services?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check out the basemaps on this [Leaflet-providers site](http://leaflet-extras.github.io/leaflet-providers/preview/index.html).

Additionally, there is a ton of options on this [(Java) OpenStreetMap site](http://josm.openstreetmap.de/wiki/Maps).

And this [Map Compare site](http://tools.geofabrik.de/mc/#15/49.0094/8.3902&num=4&mt0=mapnik&mt1=google-map&mt2=bing-map&mt3=mapnik-german) offers quite a few too.

Comment: @ElDude Please make sure to check the usage policy of the tile provider before using it at a larger scale.